# How to move multiple videos from one YouTube playlist to another, at once?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I have two playlists in my YouTube library, one is called *Research* and the other is called *Studies*. Now, I need to move all the 48 videos from the *Research* playlist to the Studies one, so that I can have fewer playlist and declutter my library. It would be tedious job to manually move them one by one, and I also plan to do this with other playlists with hundreds of videos. In the YouTube playlist section there is no option to select multiple videos at once, in order to move them. Is there any way to render this task without tediously wasting time on moving videos manually?

Answer (score 3):

You can move all the videos in one YouTube Playlist to another using the following procedure:

1. Select the originating playlist (in your example, *Research*) then select "Edit".
2. From the Playlist Edit screen select the "more" (...) icon in the upper right corner and choose "Add all to ..."
3. Select your destination playlist (in your example, *Studies*).

Now if you want to remove your videos from the original playlist

4. Select the destination playlist (in your example, *Studies*) the select "Edit".
5. From the Playlist Edit screen select "Add all to ..." like you did before.
6. This time you will see the originating playlist (in your example, *Research*) will be checked.  Un-check it and the videos will be removed from the original list.

Answer (score 0):

If the videos you want to move around are in the "music" category, then you can use music.youtube.com. When viewing a playlist of yours there, you can do multiple selection and add selected videos to another playlist that already contains a music-category video, or a new playlist, and then re-select those videos and remove them from the source playlist.